# joining two separate app models django

Tags: python, django

okay so I have just a test blog system to practice my django skills. I have 2 apps one called article on called likes here they are:

article models:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Published',auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and here is the likes models:

```
from django.db import models
from apps.article.models import Article

# Create your models here.
class Like(models.Model):
    article_id = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Likes
```

now im rendering out the pages but I want to display how many likes each article has. How can I join both these models. Change the objects.all method to also grab the likes from the Like model

Answer (score 1):

You can use FOO_set, [docs about this here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward), basically you do this to get all likes:

```
article.likes_set.all()
```

and you can just use count() to get number

Comment: so add this to my Articel model? and for some reason the django website is down for me Im at work and the server here is working hard thats why I ended up posting my question here and not looking at the django docs

Comment: you can use it in template to display all likes

Answer (score 1):

First you might want to rename article_id to article since when you use the attribute, you will actually get the article and not just the id.

In this case you seem to have a many-to-one relationship between Like and Article.  That means you need to refer to the likes as 'like_set'.  So if you happen to have the object stored in article, you can get all the likes with `article.like_set.all()` and the count with `article.like_set.count()`.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

If you're interested in fetching this ahead of time you can use prefetch_related to save the additional database calls:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

It would like something like this:

`articles = Article.objects.all().prefetch_related('like_set')`

Comment: thanks guys I think I get it now unfortunately the django site is down for me but whenever it gets back up ill take a look at it